# DLL / Typelib / COM

Tags: c++, vba

I have a C++ DLL which holds COM code. When trying to access the interface with VBA code, I am getting these error messages:

```
atlTraceCOM - ERROR : Unable to load Typelibrary. (HRESULT = 0x8002801d)
atlTraceCOM -   Verify TypelibID and major version specified with
atlTraceCOM -   IDispatchImpl, CStockPropImpl, IProvideClassInfoImpl or IProvideCLassInfo2Impl
```

I checked everthing - esp. version numbers - with OLEVIEW and the registry editor and cannot find something wrong. The COM is also working perfectly from another C++ client application (where I imported the .TLB first), but I cannot access from VBA ?!?

Any ideas?

Comment: The error means _Library not registered_. In the VBA Editor, did you include the reference?

Comment: I use: 

Set TMP = Wscript.CreateObject("Test.TMP")

I have another COM-DLL where I do exactly the same but there it works..

Comment: I found out, it has to do with version number used in the registry. But I do not understand where I have to use which numbering scheme..

Comment: It depends on how you register the DLL's ProgID. It can be either version-dependent or version-independent. A dependent ProgID would be normally something like `Test.TMP.10` for a `1.0` version. The registry should have a separate entry for the version independent ProgId, directly at the `Classes` node.

Comment: I think it has to do with the "sub-version". I use version(2.1) in the IDL file, which cannot be read properly from the registry..

Comment: If you are sure that the component was properly registered then the next thing to do is to run c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe.  The 32-bit version of the script interpreter, capable of loading legacy 32-bit components.

Comment: Why are we talking `wscript` which can't be used in VBA.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. My COM object was compiled with version 2.1 and all registry entries have been created for V2.1. When I access to the COM object, nobody accesses the 2.1 branch, only the 1.0 branch will be accessed (I watched with procmon) and marked with "NAME NOT FOUND". My COM object works only, when I use the "1.0" branch in the registry, i.e. I cannot use versioning. But in contrast with other COM objects I recognize a "browsing" of the registry "typelib" branch, which simply does not happen in my case. Is there any other hidden registry entry or COM attribute I have to set?

Comment: How does Windows know, to read the "V2.1" and not the "1.0" branch. There is no version number read from the registry - so how is this working? Is there somewhere a cache, which keeps the latest version numbers of all COM/TLB libraries?